# IOS5 iPad popup controller delegate not sending messages to parent controller

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

I'm new to iOS programming and I can't get this simple concept to work -- I just want the popup controller to be able to call a method and send data on the parent controller. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

in DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Employee.h"
#import "CompleteViewController.h"

@class EmployeesTVC;


@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>

@property (strong) UIPopoverController *popController;

-(IBAction)completeButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

in DetailViewController.m (took out irrelevant parts)

```
@implementation DetailViewController {
    __weak UIPopoverController *completePopover;
}

// ...

#pragma mark - Complete / Score popover methods

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"preparing for segue");
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
    UIPopoverController *scorePopoverController = [popoverSegue popoverController];
    [scorePopoverController setDelegate:self];
    self.popController = scorePopoverController;
}

- (IBAction)completeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    if (completePopover) {
        [completePopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showScorePopover" sender:sender];    
    }
}

- (void) scoreAssigned:(NSString *)score {
    NSLog(score);
    NSLog(@"Score Assigned");
}

// ...

@end
```

CompleteViewController.h (the popup view controller)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CompleteViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)scoreAssigned:(NSString *)score;
@end


@interface CompleteViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CompleteViewDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)okButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

CompleteViewController.m

```
#import "CompleteViewController.h"

@implementation CompleteViewController
@synthesize delegate;


- (IBAction)okButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"OK Button Pressed");
    [delegate scoreAssigned:@"100"];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your first NSLog statement firing?  "OK Button Pressed".  If not, make sure (IBAction)okButtonPressed is wired up in Interface Builder.  If so, but a break point on [delegate scoreAssigned:@"100"]; and hover over "delegate" with your mouse to see if it's nil, just to see if the delegate was successfully assigned.  If this doesn't fix it, let us know exactly where you're getting to before things stop working.

Properly presenting a UIPopoverController

```
[completePopover setDelegate:self];
[completePopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:yourButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
//or if you don't have a bar button item
[completePopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) inView:yourTargetView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Keep in mind that inView can be any subclass of UIView, like UIButton for instance.

Comment: "OK Button Pressed" is firing, and the delegate is not nil... And then nothing. The app doesn't crash, it just doesn't do anything further.

Comment: Any delegate assigned in Interface Builder?  Wonder if that might be overriding the one you assign.

Comment: Oh wait. I think it is in fact null, I just didn't realize it. There's no delegate assigned in IB. If it helps, Detail View is the detail view of a Split View.

Comment: Also, there's a warning on "scorePopoverController.delegate = self" that says "Assigning to id<UIPopoverControllerDelegate>" from incompatible type "DetailViewController *const__strong"

Comment: Do you have to use a segue to load the popover?  I'm editing the answer above with some code that should get it presented properly.